# Compiler says this function must return a value but I already have a return statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio, return, return-value

```
double ProyectMethods::getLat(const char * id) {
ifstream fileA("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\mapas\\Aeropuertos.txt", ios::in);

string latS;
double lat;

string buffer;
string nameA;
size_t n;
size_t z;

if (!fileA) { return; }

while (getline(fileA, buffer))
{
    n = buffer.find(";");
    z = buffer.find(";", n + 1);
    nameA = buffer.substr(0, n);

    if (nameA == id)
    {
        latS = buffer.substr(n + 1, z);
        lat = stod(latS);
        return lat;
    }

}

}
```

I am not sure why, but the compiler say that this function must return a value.
I already have a return over there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What should happen if the last line of `fileA` is passed, and no `nameA` was found matching `id`?

Comment: Where is your function?? Have you posted it's body only? If so, then your function must have final return statement. Or each executing branch must have return statements.

Comment: **All** control paths in a function declared to have a non-void return type *must* have a determinate return value. Your first return , `return;` specifies no value, which make no sense for a function promising one. Fixing that, consider your second, `return lat;`. What happens when `nameA == id` is *never* true. What is the result of your function? Short answer: If you promise a function result, fulfill that promise and make sure *all* control paths lead to a determinate `return` of *something*.

Answer (score 2):

The first `return` returns nothing. It must return a double value (return value of the function is double).

Also, don't forget a return at the end of the function. If the `getline()` fails, the `while` is not activated and no `return` statement is encountered. However, this should not be a problem because the compiler implicitly inserts a `return 0` if there is not a explicit one at the end of the function.

Comment: You should also mention the missing return at the end, if the call to `getline` fails.

Comment: That's right. Two mistakes with the returns in one function.

Answer (score 0):

When fileA is true and nameA != id, this function will not return anything, you should ensure your function return something in any case.